# Beautiful soup xml formatting in python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an xml dataset tag in the following format:

```
<catchphrase "id=c0">unconscionable conduct</catchphrase>
```

I think when they made the dataset they didn't format the id attribute as it has to be:

```
<catchphrase id="c0">unconscionable conduct</catchphrase>
```

However, when this goes through Beautiful Soap lib in python it comes out as follows:

```
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')
```

results in

```
 <catchphrase>
   "id=c0"&gt;application for leave to appeal
  </catchphrase>
```

or

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
```

results in

```
<html>
   <body>
    ...
     <catchphrase>
         application for leave to appeal
     </catchphrase>
    ....
```

I want to look like the second one but without the html and body tags (this is an XML document). I don't need the id attribute. I also use `soup.prettify('utf-8')` before writing it in the file but I think it is already wrongly formatted when I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such standard way of doing this, but what you can do is replacing the faulty part with the correct way, something like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '<catchphrase "id=c0">unconscionable conduct</catchphrase>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.replace('"id=', 'id="'), 'xml')
print soup
```

This results in :

```
<catchphrase id="c0">unconscionable conduct</catchphrase>
```

This is definitely a bit of a hack as there is no standard way to handle this mainly because XML is supposed to be correct before parsing by `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.